# Vector Addition in Euclidean Space

Tags: vectors

I am reading Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, and I came across something in the proof that I don't quite understand.

Let $x$ and $z$ be vectors in $\mathbb R^k$ for some $k \geq 3$ and $r >0 $ is a real number. Suppose $| z - x | = r$. Then this means that $z = x + ru$ for some unit vector $u$.

I am struggling to see why this is true. Can someone help me clarify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
z = x + (z-x) .
$$

Then normalize $z-x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r = u/\|u\|$.  This will do the job.

Comment: You should bring your notation in line with the question: $r$ is a scalar and $u$ a unit vector.